# Why react-id-swiper loop mode is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-swiper

I am trying to add a loop in react-id-swiper as per documentation but it won't work.

Below are my parameters for loop mode, Let me know if I am missing anything.

```
    const params = {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
        loop: true,
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gone through the Loop Mode / Infinite Loop example. loop parameter should be under the slidesPerView: 1 not in side the autoplay.